# Send async generator using Python requests module

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, generator, sanic

I'm using `requests` module in Python and I want to send data in request streaming way. so I applied chunked-encoded request according to [this document](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests).

However, the data to send is provided with another async method. Honestly speaking, I also use Sanic framework, and I read the stream data from `await sanic.request.stream.read()` and I want to relay the streaming data to `request` method of `requests` module.

```
async def generate_from_sanic_request(request):
  while True:
    chunk = await request.stream.read()
    if chunk is None:
      break
    yield chunk

...
requests.request(
  method="POST",
  url="my-own-url",
  data=generate_from_sanic_request, # here is the point of this question.
)
...
```

The document says that I can use the non-async generator function as the `data` argument. However, when I use an async generator there, `requests.request` cannot handle the generator.

I want to do this in a memory-efficient way, so I want to bypass the received streaming request body to requests.request method in one-by-one way.

Can I get any help to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using httpx for this instead of requests. It has an async interface and an otherwise similar implementation to requests.